# Edit "Type" Type Property in Visual Studio Editor

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Well, I've been developing an information system using WinForms, and suddenly just got stuck with this problem.

Well there is a user control wich have a "Type" Type property, I need to edit that property at edition time (in the editor) but I just can´t do it. In the property window, this property appear as readonly. Is there a way to change this property?

```
public Type ViewTemplate
  {
     get
     {
        if (viewTemplate == null)
        {
           return typeof(SomeType);
        }
        else
        {
           return viewTemplate.GetType();
        }
     }
     set
     {
        if (value != null && value.IsSubclassOf(typeof(SomeType)))
        {
           this.Controls.Clear();

           viewTemplate = (SomeType)(Control)Activator.CreateInstance(value);
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Is this a property that you have added to the UserControl? if so please show your property declaration

Comment: Are you saying you're having a collision with the "Type" reserved word in C#?

Comment: I've edited the question so you can have some more clear ideas. Thx

Comment: What does the code have to do with what you said in the question? How is the Type property creat and added to the control you are trying to chnage?

Comment: @N4TKD as I see it, it is a property with the type of Type. If you create a simple example it is indeed grayed out in the designer and is not editable.

Comment: @Mark Hall you may be right, but if the Op would connect the code to the question we may find out for sure. I am not sure how this code would connect here.

Comment: Well, what i want to do, is to edit the property at desing time, but in the property window. I was wondering if there was some attribute that i could attach to the property so it can be editable in property window